# Remove line from html table with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a html table :

```
<table>
 <tr >
  <td>name 1</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
</tr>
 <tr >
  <td>name 2</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>158,5</td>
  <td>-</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to remove/hide lines where all values are eq to "-", what's the best way to do it ?

Comment: [Link](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) see 2. example.

Comment: why down vote? this questions is legit !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easier if you add an id to your table, to avoid getting rows from other tables...

```
<table id="Example">
    ...
```

So here is an example...

```
$('#Example tr').each( function () {
    var self = $(this);
    var allEmpty = true;
    $('td', self).each( function () {
        if ($(this).text() !== '-') {
            allEmpty = false;
        }
    });

    if (allEmpty) {
        self.hide();
    }
});
```

This deletes a row where ALL fields are exactly `-`. You can modify this with more custom logic if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $("td").remove(":contains('-')");
});​
```

To delete the td with "-"

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/XNDj4/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var EmptyCheck = true;
    $('td:not(:eq(0))', self).each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() !== '-') {
            EmptyCheck = false;
            console.log($(this));
        }
    });

    if (EmptyCheck) {
        self.hide();
        EmptyCheck = true;
    }
});​
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/atif089/LWPbj/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` method.

```
$('table td').filter(function(){
   var txt = this.textContent || this.innerText;
   return txt === '-';
}).hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4snwH/

Comment: Really? textContent or innerText?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Really what?

Comment: You could just use `return $(this).text() === '-';` and be cross-browser. Half using jquery seems... weird.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine why would u do that?!?! what is the point in wrapping in a jQuery call?

Comment: @Neal because `textContent` and `innerText` do not behave the same way. The comparison might never work. `text()` is there to avoid such issues.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine  That's not true, both return text content.

Comment: @undefined yes, with different spacings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$("table tr td").each(function(){

if($(this).html() == "-")
{
   $(this).css('display','none'); // if you want to hide
   $(this).remove(); // if you want to remove
}

});
```

Comment: wouldn't `$(this).remove()` be better?

Comment: though I am not the downvoter

Comment: it's ok. i updated my answer